# Ищет ли MS SQL в нескольких индексах или выбирает только один наиболее оптимальный?

Tags: sql-server

Допустим, есть таблица с колонками A и B. На каждой колонке есть собственный индекс.

Так вот, если условие отбора будет по A и B, то SQL Server воспользуется самым оптимальным индексом, а вторым не будет пользоваться или все таки воспользуется обоими, например, отобрав сначала по одному индексу, а затем воспользовавшись на результатах отбора вторым индексом?

Я склоняюсь, что будет выбран только оддин индекс, но что-то нагуглить подтверждения не могу...

Comment: Возможен вариант использования одного индекса, и вариант использования обоих индексов по отдельности с последующим слиянием или пересечением полученных результатов. Вариант "сначала по одному индексу, а затем воспользовавшись на результатах отбора вторым индексом" - нереализуем чисто теоретически.

Comment: Перед тем, как выполнить отбор данных, выбирается самый оптимальный индекс путем анализа запроса и главным образом основываясь на секции WHERE запроса. Остальные индексы не будут учитываться, за исключением некластеризованных индексов, когда возможен переход к кластеризованному индексу для дальнейшего отбора данных.

Comment: @Akina Да, вот про слияние я тоже подумал, что параллельно можно с 2-ух индексов отобрать, а потом найти пересечение.

Comment: Некоторые СУБД такое умеют. Но используют достаточно редко. Умеет ли ms sql сказать не могу, запрос к гуглу "sql server index merge" ничего интересного не дал (но ms вполне может эту операцию называть как то по особенному). Да и не имеет это особого значения, просто смотрите планы выполнения, в них много интересного бывает

Comment: *Но используют достаточно редко.* A это - простая арифметика. Чтобы был смысл использовать индекс, статистика (которая сама по себе не образец истины) должна показывать достаточно высокую селективность как индекса, так и мержа результата из него с таким же результатом из второго индекса. Но чтобы выборка по второму индексу плюс мерж стали выгоднее прямого скана, там вообще селективность должна быть заоблачной - но тогда почему не было начато с о скана по второму индексу?

Comment: Если все, что нужно в результирующем наборе, можно получить из двух индексов, то будут использованы эти два индекса. Если они не покрывают запрос, то скорее всего будет использован какой-то один + lookup из кластерного индекса/таблицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Допустим, есть таблица с колонками A и B. На каждой колонке есть собственный индекс.
>   ... если условие отбора будет по A и B, то SQL Server воспользуется самым
>   оптимальным индексом, а вторым не будет пользоваться или все таки
>   воспользуется обоими ... ?

Оптимизатор может использовать оба индекса, может только один какой-то, может ни одним из индексов не воспользоваться. В общем случае это зависит от запроса, определения таблицы и индексов, данных в таблице, состояния статистик, версии SqlServer, настроек сессии и других факторов.

Вот пример, когда оптимизатор использует два индекса на одной таблице.

Таблица

```
CREATE TABLE #dummy
(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    A char(1),
    B char(1),
    Filler binary(100)
);
```

Данные

```
INSERT INTO #dummy (Id, A, B, Filler)
SELECT N, CHAR(48 + N % 10), CHAR(65 + N % 26), 0x
FROM Numbers -- таблица с натуральными числами
WHERE N BETWEEN 1 AND 10000;
```

Индексы

```
CREATE INDEX IX_dummy_A ON #dummy (A);
CREATE INDEX IX_dummy_B ON #dummy (B);
```

Запрос с условием **AND** по столбцам `A` и `B`

```
SELECT Id
FROM #dummy
WHERE A = '7' AND B = 'F';
```

План запроса

[image: план 1]

т.е. фактически оптимизатор преобразовал запрос в соединение

```
SELECT ixb.Id
FROM (
    SELECT Id
    FROM #dummy WITH (INDEX(IX_dummy_B))
    WHERE B = 'F'
    ) ixb
JOIN (
    SELECT Id
    FROM #dummy WITH (INDEX(IX_dummy_A))
    WHERE A = '7'
) ixa ON ixa.Id = ixb.Id;
```

Теперь с условием **OR** по столбцам `A` и `B`

```
SELECT Id
FROM #dummy
WHERE A = '7' OR B = 'F';
```

[image: план 2]

что эквивалентно выборке без повторов из объединения

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id
FROM (
    SELECT Id
    FROM #dummy WITH (INDEX(IX_dummy_A))
    WHERE A = '7'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id
    FROM #dummy WITH (INDEX(IX_dummy_B))
    WHERE B = 'F'
) u;
```

Запрос с условием **AND** по столбцам `A` и `B`, но индексы не покрывают запрос

```
SELECT *
FROM #dummy
WHERE A = '7' AND B = 'F';
```

[image: план 3]

отчасти похоже на первый случай, но добавилось соединение с *Key Lookup*, чтобы достать данные столбца `Filler`.

Этот же запрос, но с **OR**

```
SELECT *
FROM #dummy
WHERE A = '7' OR B = 'F';
```

и оптимизатор решает, что сканирование кластерного индекса выгоднее

[image: план 4]

Та же самая таблица, те же индексы, но другие данные, первый запрос (`SELECT Id ... WHERE ... AND ...`)

[image: план 5]

оптимизатор использует только один индекс (по столбцу `B`), добирая остальное из кластерного индекса.